# Open Office Spreadsheet Calculations

Tags: formula, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I need to fill in price fields in our billing system, and I need to basically do 6 * 1.99, 8 * 1.99, 10 * 1.99, all the way through 64. Then do the same thing for 6 - 64 with 1.79$, then again with 6 - 64 with 1.59$.

I was doing this manually by hand, and just using Windows Calculator, but I realized it was going to take forever. I was going to write a small program in C# to do it, but would there be an easy way to do this with calculations in Open Office Spreadsheet?

I would just need to do something like =A1*B1, =A2*B1, etc.

Would there be anyway to do something like...A(This row index)*B(This row index) though? Would it be possible to have it automatically fill out these fields with that formula?

Comment: do you need all results seperately or do you want to add all of the results for one row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can do the following:

You can write the prices in column A (starting with row 2 1,99, 1,59...) and all the numbers in row 1 (starting with column B 6,8,12....)

if you have this you can just put:

B$1*$A2

Into coulm b2.

Now you can paste this formula by dragging the spot at the cell corner to other cells. The Row number will automaticly change.

[image: columns, rows and formulas]

Comment: another useful hint: if you type 6 and 8 into two cells like above, then select them and start dragging the handle. Open Office will guess the next numbers and go on with 10, 12 and so on. The same with the prices on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW()` to get the current row number.  So for example, you could use a series of formulas like this:

```
=(ROW() + 2) * 2  |  =A1*1.99  |  =A1*1.79  |  =A1*1.59
```

Then copy the formulas down as many rows as needed.

Comment: Would it be possible to do like =A(ROW())+B(COL2VALUE())? It didn't work so I assume I am not using the proper syntax. =ROW()*1.99 would be fine, except I would like to be able to change the prices at a later time and have them automatically update. Thanks!

Comment: You could place the prices along the top row like @Chris's answer, and reference them like `=A2*B1  |  =A2*C1  |  =A2*D1` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Put the price in `A1` and use it in your formulas as `$A$1`, this way its row and column will not progress as you drag your formula down or to the right.